# Compress 16 bit raw data in webgl

Tags: opengl, webgl, compression

I have a 3D volume where every voxel is 16 bits. Is there anyway I can use some kind of compression to store the data so I can use less video ram?
Webgl supported different compressiosn if you enable them with extension, but can I use them for a one channel data?

Like `WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc` only supports rgb and rgba data:

```
COMPRESSED_RGB_S3TC_DXT1_EXT
COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT1_EXT
COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT3_EXT
COMPRESSED_RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_EXT
```

If its not possible in webgl, is it supported in OpenGL to compress a 16 bit values with one channel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no.

S3TC and other compression formats will destroy your 16bit values.

Texture compression formats have a fixed compressed size and therefore need to be lossy in order to ensure this.

If you need 16bits of lossless data you must use a non-compressed format. Ideally `GL_R16UI`.

Comment: But if its ok with a little loss, can I use the S3TC with just a 16 bit value or is it just for compression rgb values of floats?

Comment: Most compression methods compress a 4x4 block of 24bit RGB values into a 4x4 block of TWO 15bit RGB (5bit of red) values and 2 in-betweens colors for a total of 4 colors in a 4x4 block.
Try it and see if it's acceptable for your project to cut down 16 bits down to 5, with only 4 values per 4x4 block.